# Where did the "Outer" and "Inner" Product nomenclature come from?

Tags: inner-products, math-history, outer-product

I have recently become familiar with the concept of the outer and inner products on vector spaces - but why have they come to be called the "outer product" and "inner product"? What is the history behind this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476754/what-is-inner-about-the-inner-product

Comment: http://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html quotes: "When the German Sanskrit scholar Hermann Günther Grassman (1809-1877) developed the general algebra of hypercomplex numbers, he realized that more than one type of multiplication is possible. To two of the many possible types he gave the names inner and outer. The names seem to have been chosen because they are antonyms rather than for any intrinsic meaning."

Comment: Compare also with inner semidirect product and outer semidirect product of, say, groups.

Comment: See [Hermann Günther Grassman's contribution to math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Grassmann#Mathematician).