# Significance of naming inner and outer products

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

So in linear algebra, inner product is when you take the dot product of vectors--multiplying the corresponding entries of the vectors and then summing them up--getting a scalar. While outer product is when you multiply each entry of one vector with each entry of the other vectors--getting a matrix.

Why is the first one called "inner" product and the second one called "outer?"

Comment: Your outer product sounds like a vector product, which is not what I'd think of as outer (typically the 'cross product' would be the outer product, and then the naming comes from inner product staying in the same plane and the outer product moving out of the plane orthogonally (loosely put)

Comment: Related: ["Where did the 'Outer' and 'Inner' Product nomenclature come from?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2765192/409). No answers, but one comment quotes from the ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics"](http://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html) pages (that's the tripod link) the notion that "inner" and "outer" were chosen by Grassman simply because they were antonyms.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476754/what-is-inner-about-the-inner-product